# If i use os.networkInterfaces() and deploy to server, can i get server ip?

Tags: node.js, ip, apollo

Currently I'm using apolloserver + nodejs to my project
and i want to get server ip address for monitoring log in Sentry.

Soon i'm gonna add more servers so i want to get which server clients are using for monitoring.

If i use os.networkInterfaces(), can i get server ip address?

I was trying to use this code

```
const nets = networkInterfaces()
const ip = nets.en0[0].family != 'IPv6' ? nets.en0[0].address : nets.en0[1].address

Logger.setUser(ip)  // to Sentry
```

Comment: `os.networkInterfaces()` returns a array of available NICs. Just pick the right one you need.

Comment: Does it have aws ip address itself after I publish it? @Marc

Comment: Dont know what you need, public ip, private ip?  Why dont you post the output of `os.networkInterfaces()` and specify what kind of ip address you need?

Comment: I printed ip address. it's different from aws ip address.
What i received: 192.XXX.XX.XX (eth0) and 
What server really is: 203.XXX.X.XXX @Marc

Comment: 192.x.x.x is a private IPv4, 203.x.x.x is a public IPv4. What kind of IP Address you need? Public or Private? You are providing to few informations. Everything has to be pulled out of your nose. Explain specific what you want/need.